# Fullcalendar: add tooltip in every slot of the dayrender

Tags: fullcalendar, timeline

I am trying to add the resource value and the date in every single slot of the calendar with timeline view. When the mouse is over on the slot, I want to see tooltip with the details of the Resource and the date.
Please see that the calendar is with timeline view with many resources and many events.
Please see the image.[image]

Comment: Why? The resource value and the date are already shown in the row and column headers - that's the whole point of them. Anyway this isn't possible. The cells you see a are a visual illusion caused by overlaying multiple HTML tables on top.of each other. There isn't actually a single "cell" you can target to place this data.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your reply. Do you know how to activate vertical scrollbar in the fullcalendar?

Comment: The height and contentHeight settings will affect whether you get a scrollbar, as will the height of the container in which the calendar is located. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/sizing for more info.